# Function with Date as Parameter - Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to do a function that takes in a DATE as parameter (FORMATED as 'MM/DD/YYYY' but it returns null.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_date  (h_date IN DATE)
RETURN DATE
AS
    emp_hire_date DATE;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
    SELECT hire_date INTO emp_hire_date FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE hire_date < h_date
    )
    LOOP
    RETURN emp_hire_date;
    END LOOP;
END;

SELECT func_date('01/01/1990') FROM DUAL; --this returns NULL value
```

So I tested a PL/SQL block to check but the VARIABLE that was set to DATE was not printing. Can someone help, please? Thanks!

```
DECLARE
    emp_hire_date DATE;
BEGIN
FOR RECORD IN (
    SELECT hire_date INTO emp_hire_date
    FROM employees
    WHERE hire_date < '01/01/1990') LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hire date is:' || emp_hire_date);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I know the block works, because here is the output:

```
Hire date is:
Hire date is:
Hire date is:
```

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you wrote doesn't make much sense and, although *compiles*, does things in a wrong manner.

Don't `SELECT INTO` within a cursor `FOR` loop. You don't want to use locally declare variable, but value stored in a cursor variable - if you want to use a loop.

Though, as you return a value as soon as you fetch *something* (which is the very first row), I don't know why you use a loop at all.

Anyway: here's an example that *simulates* your code, but this one returns a value. I ran it on Scott's schema, so table and column names are slightly different than yours. Compare this code with yours.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_date (h_date IN DATE)
  2    RETURN DATE
  3  AS                               -- no local variable declaration
  4  BEGIN
  5    FOR rec IN (SELECT hiredate    -- no INTO clause here
  6                FROM EMP
  7                WHERE hiredate < h_date
  8               )
  9    LOOP
 10      RETURN rec.hiredate;         -- return cursor variable value
 11    END LOOP;
 12  END;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT func_date(to_date('01/01/1990', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) FROM DUAL;  -- pass DATE, not a string

FUNC_DATE(
----------
17/12/1980

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, was able to successfully write the function based on your code. Though I need it to have more than one result. You've given me ideas to tinker about. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Tr y using `To_Date`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_date  (h_date IN DATE)
RETURN DATE
AS
    emp_hire_date DATE;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (
    SELECT hire_date INTO emp_hire_date FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE to_date(hire_date,'MM/dd/yyyy') < to_date(h_date,'MM/dd/yyyy')
    )
    LOOP
    RETURN emp_hire_date;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar, I did that to the function but still same NULL result. If I can make it work on the PL/SQL block example I tested, maybe easier to debug the function.

Answer (score 0):

@Littlefoot thanks for the input. I was able to write the function successfully based on your code, but I knew there will be more than one result so I wrote a block using cursor to test and it was successful.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT hire_date
        FROM employees
        WHERE hire_date < '01/01/1990';
    h_date DATE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO h_date;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hire date is: ' ||h_date);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;
END;
```

RESULT IS:

```
Hire date is: 06/17/1987
Hire date is: 09/21/1989
Hire date is: 09/17/1987


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Then based on the block I wrote, I created the function with a cursor:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_date (h_date IN DATE)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
    c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN c1 FOR
        SELECT hire_date
        FROM employees
        WHERE hire_date < h_date;
    LOOP
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    RETURN c1;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Calling the function and passing the date:

```
SELECT func_date('01/01/1990') FROM DUAL;
```

The result is below. Not really what I wanted but I think I can figure it out soon on how to output the result as record

[image]